# MySQL Sum of Field Always Show NULL

Tags: mysql, ifnull

I have a problem to sum of field that always show null,
I already tried all of these MySQL query,

```
(SUM(IFNULL(topup_amount,0))) AS total,
SUM(topup_amount) AS total2,
COALESCE(SUM(topup_amount),110),
IFNULL(SUM(topup_amount), 0),
COALESCE(SUM(topup_amount), 0)
```

But always show null result, I need 0 (zero) result.
Anyone know about this?

Comment: Did you try `SUM(COALESCE(topup_amount,0)` (though I cannot see that this would make much difference - I suspect the error lies elsewhere)

Comment: I can not see something wrong at least for the statement `SUM(IFNULL(topup_amount,0))`. Have you checked how the result set looks like after you applied `ifnull` but without aggregation?

Comment: this is the query i'm using, 

SELECT (SUM(IFNULL(topup_amount,0))) AS total,
    SUM(topup_amount) AS total2,
    COALESCE(SUM(topup_amount),110),
IFNULL(SUM(topup_amount), 0),
COALESCE(SUM(topup_amount), 0)
   FROM
    ap_topup_request
   WHERE
    retailer_id = 34290
   AND date(topup_time) >= (
    DATE_ADD(
     CURDATE(),
     INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY
    ) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
   )
   AND date(topup_time) < DATE_ADD(
    CURDATE(),
    INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY
   )
   GROUP BY
    WEEK (topup_time)
   ORDER BY
    WEEK (topup_time) DESC
   LIMIT 1

Comment: Are you sure that your `where` condition actually returns a non zero result set? E.g. `ifnull` return `null` when working on empty sets.

Comment: sure, i think i've found the solution, it because the group by week syntax. After removed that one, finally i get the ifnull value.

Answer (score 0):

After check all my query the problem is **GROUP BY WEEK (topup_time)**. **I removed this one**, and finally i get the ifnull value. I don't know why it can be happen.